# How to make Samba on an Ubuntu server accessible in multi user on Windows OS?

Tags: 14.04, server, samba

My smb.conf :

```
koko@rumah:~$ cat /etc/samba/smb.conf
    #
    # Sample configuration file for the Samba suite for Debian GNU/Linux.
    #
    #
    # This is the main Samba configuration file. You should read the
    # smb.conf(5) manual page in order to understand the options listed
    # here. Samba has a huge number of configurable options most of which
    # are not shown in this example
    #
    # Some options that are often worth tuning have been included as
    # commented-out examples in this file.
    #  - When such options are commented with ";", the proposed setting
    #    differs from the default Samba behaviour
    #  - When commented with "#", the proposed setting is the default
    #    behaviour of Samba but the option is considered important
    #    enough to be mentioned here
    #
    # NOTE: Whenever you modify this file you should run the command
    # "testparm" to check that you have not made any basic syntactic
    # errors.

    #======================= Global Settings =======================

    [global]
            passdb backend = tdbsam
            passwd chat = *Enter\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *Retype\snew\s*\spassword:* %n\n *password\supdated\ssuccessfully* .
            syslog = 0
            panic action = /usr/share/samba/panic-action %d
            dns proxy = no
            map to guest = bad user
            server role = standalone server
            encrypt passwords = yes
            passwd program = /usr/bin/passwd %u
            usershare allow guests = yes
            obey pam restrictions = yes
            log file = /var/log/samba/log.%m
            max log size = 1000
            workgroup = WORKGROUP
            unix password sync = yes
            pam password change = yes
            server string = %h server (Samba, Ubuntu)

    ## Browsing/Identification ###

    # Change this to the workgroup/NT-domain name your Samba server will part of

    # server string is the equivalent of the NT Description field

    # Windows Internet Name Serving Support Section:
    # WINS Support - Tells the NMBD component of Samba to enable its WINS Server
       wins support = yes

    # WINS Server - Tells the NMBD components of Samba to be a WINS Client
    # Note: Samba can be either a WINS Server, or a WINS Client, but NOT both
    #   wins server = w.x.y.z

    # This will prevent nmbd to search for NetBIOS names through DNS.

    #### Networking ####

    # The specific set of interfaces / networks to bind to
    # This can be either the interface name or an IP address/netmask;
    # interface names are normally preferred
    ;   interfaces = 127.0.0.0/8 eth0

    # Only bind to the named interfaces and/or networks; you must use the
    # 'interfaces' option above to use this.
    # It is recommended that you enable this feature if your Samba machine is
    # not protected by a firewall or is a firewall itself.  However, this
    # option cannot handle dynamic or non-broadcast interfaces correctly.
    ;   bind interfaces only = yes



    #### Debugging/Accounting ####

    # This tells Samba to use a separate log file for each machine
    # that connects

    # Cap the size of the individual log files (in KiB).

    # If you want Samba to only log through syslog then set the following
    # parameter to 'yes'.
    #   syslog only = no

    # We want Samba to log a minimum amount of information to syslog. Everything
    # should go to /var/log/samba/log.{smbd,nmbd} instead. If you want to log
    # through syslog you should set the following parameter to something higher.

    # Do something sensible when Samba crashes: mail the admin a backtrace


    ####### Authentication #######

    # Server role. Defines in which mode Samba will operate. Possible
    # values are "standalone server", "member server", "classic primary
    # domain controller", "classic backup domain controller", "active
    # directory domain controller".
    #
    # Most people will want "standalone sever" or "member server".
    # Running as "active directory domain controller" will require first
    # running "samba-tool domain provision" to wipe databases and create a
    # new domain.

    # If you are using encrypted passwords, Samba will need to know what
    # password database type you are using.


    # This boolean parameter controls whether Samba attempts to sync the Unix
    # password with the SMB password when the encrypted SMB password in the
    # passdb is changed.

    # For Unix password sync to work on a Debian GNU/Linux system, the following
    # parameters must be set (thanks to Ian Kahan <<kahan@informatik.tu-muenchen.de> for
    # sending the correct chat script for the passwd program in Debian Sarge).

    # This boolean controls whether PAM will be used for password changes
    # when requested by an SMB client instead of the program listed in
    # 'passwd program'. The default is 'no'.

    # This option controls how unsuccessful authentication attempts are mapped
    # to anonymous connections

    ########## Domains ###########

    #
    # The following settings only takes effect if 'server role = primary
    # classic domain controller', 'server role = backup domain controller'
    # or 'domain logons' is set
    #

    # It specifies the location of the user's
    # profile directory from the client point of view) The following
    # required a [profiles] share to be setup on the samba server (see
    # below)
    ;   logon path = \\%N\profiles\%U
    # Another common choice is storing the profile in the user's home directory
    # (this is Samba's default)
    #   logon path = \\%N\%U\profile

    # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
    # It specifies the location of a user's home directory (from the client
    # point of view)
    ;   logon drive = H:
    #   logon home = \\%N\%U

    # The following setting only takes effect if 'domain logons' is set
    # It specifies the script to run during logon. The script must be stored
    # in the [netlogon] share
    # NOTE: Must be store in 'DOS' file format convention
    ;   logon script = logon.cmd

    # This allows Unix users to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
    # RPC pipe.  The example command creates a user account with a disabled Unix
    # password; please adapt to your needs
    ; add user script = /usr/sbin/adduser --quiet --disabled-password --gecos "" %u

    # This allows machine accounts to be created on the domain controller via the
    # SAMR RPC pipe.
    # The following assumes a "machines" group exists on the system
    ; add machine script  = /usr/sbin/useradd -g machines -c "%u machine account" -d /var/lib/samba -s /bin/false %u

    # This allows Unix groups to be created on the domain controller via the SAMR
    # RPC pipe.
    ; add group script = /usr/sbin/addgroup --force-badname %g

    ############ Misc ############

    # Using the following line enables you to customise your configuration
    # on a per machine basis. The %m gets replaced with the netbios name
    # of the machine that is connecting
    ;   include = /home/samba/etc/smb.conf.%m

    # Some defaults for winbind (make sure you're not using the ranges
    # for something else.)
    ;   idmap uid = 10000-20000
    ;   idmap gid = 10000-20000
    ;   template shell = /bin/bash

    # Setup usershare options to enable non-root users to share folders
    # with the net usershare command.

    # Maximum number of usershare. 0 (default) means that usershare is disabled.
    ;   usershare max shares = 100

    # Allow users who've been granted usershare privileges to create
    # public shares, not just authenticated ones

    #======================= Share Definitions =======================

    # Un-comment the following (and tweak the other settings below to suit)
    # to enable the default home directory shares. This will share each
    # user's home directory as \\server\username
    ;[homes]
    ;   comment = Home Directories
    ;   browseable = no

    # By default, the home directories are exported read-only. Change the
    # next parameter to 'no' if you want to be able to write to them.
    ;   read only = yes

    # File creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
    # create files with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
    ;   create mask = 0700

    # Directory creation mask is set to 0700 for security reasons. If you want to
    # create dirs. with group=rw permissions, set next parameter to 0775.
    ;   directory mask = 0700

    # By default, \\server\username shares can be connected to by anyone
    # with access to the samba server.
    # Un-comment the following parameter to make sure that only "username"
    # can connect to \\server\username
    # This might need tweaking when using external authentication schemes
    ;   valid users = %S

    # Un-comment the following and create the netlogon directory for Domain Logons
    # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
    ;[netlogon]
    ;   comment = Network Logon Service
    ;   path = /home/samba/netlogon
    ;   guest ok = yes
    ;   read only = yes

    # Un-comment the following and create the profiles directory to store
    # users profiles (see the "logon path" option above)
    # (you need to configure Samba to act as a domain controller too.)
    # The path below should be writable by all users so that their
    # profile directory may be created the first time they log on
    ;[profiles]
    ;   comment = Users profiles
    ;   path = /home/samba/profiles
    ;   guest ok = no
    ;   browseable = no
    ;   create mask = 0600
    ;   directory mask = 0700

    [ivan]
       comment = ivan
       path = /media/doc1st/files/ivan
       guest ok = yes
       browseable = yes
       create mask = 0600
       directory mask = 0700

    [adrian]
       comment = adrian
       path = /media/doc1st/files/adrian
       guest ok = yes
       browseable = yes
       create mask = 0600
       directory mask = 0700

    [indra]
       comment = indra
       path = /media/doc1st/files/indra
       guest ok = yes
       browseable = yes
       create mask = 0600
       directory mask = 0700

    [inesdoc]
       comment = inesdoc
       path = /media/doc1st/files/ines
       guest ok = yes
       browseable = yes
       create mask = 0600
       directory mask = 0700

    [ines]
       comment = ines
       path = /media/ines1st
       guest ok = yes
       browseable = yes
       create mask = 0600
       directory mask = 0700

    [music]
       comment = music
       path = /media/doc1st/music
       guest ok = yes
       browseable = yes
       create mask = 0600
       directory mask = 0700

    [movies]
       comment = movies
       path = /media/misc1st/movies
       guest ok = yes
       browseable = yes
       create mask = 0600
       directory mask = 0700

    [public]
            directory mask = 0700
            comment = public
            path = /media/doc1st/files/public
            create mask = 0600
            writeable = yes
            browseable = yes
            public = yes


    [printers]
       comment = All Printers
       browseable = no
       path = /var/spool/samba
       printable = yes
       guest ok = no
       read only = yes
       create mask = 0700

    # Windows clients look for this share name as a source of downloadable
    # printer drivers
    [print$]
       comment = Printer Drivers
       path = /var/lib/samba/printers
       browseable = yes
       read only = yes
       guest ok = no
    # Uncomment to allow remote administration of Windows print drivers.
    # You may need to replace 'lpadmin' with the name of the group your
    # admin users are members of.
    # Please note that you also need to set appropriate Unix permissions
    # to the drivers directory for these users to have write rights in it
    ;   write list = root, @lpadmin
```

user i have in ubuntu server :

```
koko@rumah:~$ cut -d: -f1 /etc/passwd
root
daemon
bin
sys
sync
games
man
lp
mail
news
uucp
proxy
www-data
backup
list
irc
gnats
nobody
libuuid
syslog
messagebus
landscape
sshd
koko
mysql
colord
avahi
plex
vnstat
deluge
debian-deluged
bind
apt-mirror
kogoro
koiv
adrian
ines
```

[samba user](http://ivan.click/img/samba%20user.PNG) : koiv, koko, ines, adrian, kogoro, nobody

when i want to connect with other windows os in 2nd desktop, i get this error message : the network folder specified is currently mapped using a different user name and password. to connect using a different user name and password, first disconnect any existing mapping tro this network share :(

[map network drive](http://ivan.click/img/error.smb.connect.02.PNG) 
[error message](http://ivan.click/img/error.smb.connect.01.PNG) 
how to fix?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to get around this issue which is a windows issue you will need to add some different "hosts" at least in name in your windows host file.

```
192.168.0.100   server1alias1   server1alias1
192.168.0.100   server1alias2   server1alias2
```

After that you can login using the different information.

```
\\server1alias1\folder1 as user user1
\\server1alias2\folder2 as user user2
```

Let me know if you have any issues.

A second solution is to try and edit the samba file itself.

```
[global]
...
netbios aliases = alias1 alias2 readonly
```

[source](https://superuser.com/questions/95872/sambawindows-allow-multiple-connections-by-different-users)

Comment: okay that fix the problem :-) now how to login with other account ?, i can login with samba user koko only in every pc i have, how to login with different user?